# When will the following set be a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n, \beta \in\Bbb R$.
Under what condition for those numbers will the set $M=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n): \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i=\beta\}$ be a subspace?

I would appreciate a thorough explanation of what is going on here and what I need to do.
All I know is that a subspace is a subset of vector space that is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. So I need to check the closure for $2$ vectors in $M$. And I know that $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i=\beta\iff\alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2 x_2+\cdots+\alpha_n x_n=\beta$.

Comment: What value must $\beta$ be for it to be a subspace? If $M$ is a subspace and $x \in M$ then $2x \in M$ for all $2$s.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha_k = 0$ for all $k$, then what value must $\beta$ be?

Suppose at least one $\alpha_k \neq 0$.

If $x \in M$ then $\sum_k \alpha_k x_k = \beta$.

If $M$ is a subspace, then $2x \in M$ and so
$\sum_k \alpha_k (2x_k) = 2 \beta = \beta$.

What value must $\beta$ have for this to be satisfied?

From this you can conclude that if $M$ is a subspace, then $\beta$ must
have this particular value.

For the other direction, suppose that $\beta$ has this particular value
with arbitrary $\alpha_k$, and
show that the corresponding $M$ is a subspace.

Comment: Ohhh, $\beta$ must be zero.  But what is $x$? I mean I know $x$ is arbitrary, but can you give me an example of some vector $x$?

Comment: $x$ is an element of the set $M$.

Comment: The above shows that if $M$ is a subspace then $\beta$ must be zero. Now show that if $\beta = 0$, then $M$ is a subspace. In particular, pick $x,y \in M$ and show that $x+y \in M$ and $\lambda x \in M$ for any scalar $\lambda$.

Comment: $x$ is a vector with real coefficients? It could be $x=(0,0,0)$ or $x=(1,-5,6,8,9)$?

Comment: $M$ is a set that contains a collection of elements that satisfy some rule. I am using the symbol $x$ to represent an arbitrary element of that set.

Comment: For the purposes of the above, you could pick a specific $x$, say all ones.